# Find the maximum of 3 numbers without branching

Tags: atomic-code-golf

This time around your goal is to find the maximum of 3 integers (from -(2^31) to 2^31 - 1 in binary 2's complement) without using branching or loops.

You are **only** allowed to use

- Inequality/Equality (`==`, `>`, `>=`, `<`, `<=`, `!=`) These count as **2** tokens.
- Arithmetic (`+`, `-`, `*`, `/`)
- Logical Operators (`!` not, `&&` and, `||`  or)
- Bitwise Operators (`~` not, `&` and, `|` or, `^` xor, `<<`, `>>`, `>>>` arithmetic and logical left and right shifts)
- Constants. 0 tokens
- Variable assignment. 0 tokens

Input 3 variables as `a`, `b` and `c`. Output the maximum number.

Standard atomic code-golf rules apply. If you have any questions please leave them in the comments. One token is any of the above with the special rules.

Comment: What about defining an extra function? If this is allowed, how many tokens does it count as?

Comment: @voidpigeon You are only allowed to have one function, the one that takes the 3 inputs and outputs.

Comment: At first glance I thought, _"[we've had this before.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/12514)"_, but I think comparators costing 2 changes the game quite a bit.

Comment: @primo I specifically asked for 3 inputs because it actually allows for some interesting improvements

Comment: Can the integers be repeated? eg: `f(3,3,3)`? And is integer division allowed?

Comment: @Ourous Yes, just return or output the maximum. I'll allow integer division.

Comment: Can we use inbuilt functions?

Comment: Can we use `:` and `?`?

Comment: @Joshpbarron, that would be branching

Comment: ARM assembly has non-branching conditional instructions. Can I use those?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Javascript 10 tokens

*Edit* Using < and * instead of bit fiddling - as pointed out in comments, bits operations may fail for input near the range limit (over 30 bits)

```
function Max(x,y,z)
{
  var d=y-x;
  x=y-d*(d<0);
  d=x-z;
  return x-d*(d<0);
}
```

## C 8 tokens

Language agnostic in fact, any C like language will do. To be picky, in standard C it's not portable because right shift may not extend the sign (but in common implementations it does).

In C (and C++, C#, and Java I think) we can easily handle overflow problems using bigger temporary values:

```
int Max(int x, int y, int z)
{
    long long X = x;
    long long Y = y;
    long long Z = z;
    long long D = Y-X;
    X=Y-((D>>63)&D);
    D=X-Z;
    return (int) (X-((D>>63)&D));
}
```

Comment: I'm being picky, but using C `int`s your code doesn't work for x=2147483647, y = -2, z=0. Your choice if you want to change it

Answer (score 11):

## Javascript

**6 tokens**

```
function maxOf3(a, b, c) {
    (b>a) && (a=b);
    (c>a) && (a=c);
    return a;
}
```

Comment: +1 I see shortcut evaluation as a type of branching, but it's not forbidden in the rules

Comment: I would consider this as branching, haha

Comment: @edc65 It is. Allowing `&&` and `||` was likely an oversight, which should be pointed out, rather than exploited.

Comment: @primo This was an interesting issue. I believe some CISC architectures have instructions that include conditional statements, so I'm not sure how those would be counted.

Comment: I guess it should be 4 tokens i.e 2 `&&`, `<` and `>`. The `=` is used as an assignment and counts as 0

Comment: @ClydeLobo It's `6` because `<` and `>` cost double.

Answer (score 6):

### C: 10 tokens

```c
int max(int a, int b, int c)
{
    a += (b > a) * (b - a);
    a += (c > a) * (c - a);
    return a;
}
```

Inspired by @openorclose's answer, but converted to C and made branchless using multiplication rather than short circuit boolean operators.

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript

**14 tokens**

```
function max (a, b, c)
{
    var ab = (a >= b) * a + (a < b) * b;
    return (ab >= c) * ab + (ab < c) * c;
}
```

Comment: You are not allowed to create new functions

Comment: :( 14 tokens then

Answer (score 2):

### Many languages (Python) (10 tokens)

```
def max3(x,y,z):
    m = x ^ ((x ^ y) & -(x < y))
    return m ^ ((m ^ z) & -(m < z))

print max3(-1,-2,-3) # -1
print max3(-1,2,10) # 10
```

https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerMinOrMax

Oh, someone already posted it :)

Comment: You are not allowed to create new functions

Comment: Ahh ok! Didn't read the comments :)

Comment: @qwr I don't get it, you said: `You are only allowed to have one function, the one that takes the 3 inputs and outputs.` That's exactly what this answer has. The 2 prints are just test cases

Comment: @Cruncher I edited the answer I did `max2(max2(x,y),z)` initially :)

Comment: @Mardoxx ah. Well +1

Answer (score 1):

## C++11: 15 tokens

Using only arithmetic and bitwise operators (since equality and boolean logic operators make it too easy)...

```c++11
#include <iostream>

auto max(int32_t a, int32_t b, int32_t c)->int32_t {
  return c - ((c - (a - ((a - b) & (a - b) >> 31))) & (c - (a - ((a - b) & (a - b) >> 31))) >> 31);
}

auto main()->int {
  // test harness
  std::cout << max(9, 38, 7) << std::endl;
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Fail for big numbers (>2^30), see comment http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/32476/#comment68870_32477

Comment: Looks fine to me: http://ideone.com/pEsvG3

Comment: Did you atctually read the comment? I think 2billions is greater than 0 [http://ideone.com/vlcnq9 ]

Comment: Ah i see; yes it does have a problem with those numbers in your other comment, when a 0 is involved.  But not for 2^30 as you said.  http://ideone.com/LicmXa

Comment: It's not the 0 involved. The problem are big numbers and overflow, try max(2000000000, -200000000, 1111111111).

Answer (score 0):

## J (Not competing)

I was just wondering what the a solution in J would look like. This uses a `,` and a `#` though, so it won't be competing.

```
((a<b),(b<c),(c<a))#b,c,a
```

This would compete, but is way too long, with 9 tokens:

```
(b*a<:b)+(c*b<c)+(a*c<a)
```

Answer (score 0):

we have the following assumptions:

- max(a;b)=(a+b + |a-b|)/2
- max(a;b;c)=max(max(a;b);c)
- abs(a)=(a + (a >> 31)) ^ (a >> 31)

we can use the pseudo-code:

> function max(a,b,c)
>
> {
>
> out1=( (a+b) +  (( (a-b) + ((a-b) >> 31)) ^ ((a-b)>> 31))) div 2
>
> out2=( (out1+c) +  (( (out1-c) + ((out1-c) >> 31)) ^ ((out1-c)>> 31))) div 2
>
> return out2
>
> }

Comment: Please write actual code, and provide the count of tokens in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

### C# (2nd try)

I got it... No integrated functions...

But is it allowed to use other integrated datatypes or just plain int? If allowed I would propose:

```
int foo2(int a, int b, int c)
{
   var x = new SortedList<int,int>();

   x[a] = 1;
   x[b] = 1;
   x[c] = 1;

   return x.Keys[2];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### javascript 8 tokens

although similar to @openorclose's answer, i do actually use the logical operators for the assignment itself.

```
function max( a, b, c ) {
    x=( a > b && a) || b;
    return ( x > c && x ) || c;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mendelthecoder/Lj2zC/)

Answer (score 0):

### R (10 tokens)

```
function max(a, b, c) {
  max <- a
  max <- max + (b - max) * (b > max)
  max <- max + (c - max) * (c > max)
  return(max)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Brainfuck (Not competing)

```
>,[-<+>>>+<<]>,[-<+>>>+<<]>[>[-<->>]<<]<[-]>[-]>[-]<<<[->>>>+<<<<]>>>>[-<+>>>+<<]>,[-<+>>>+<<]>[>[-<->>]<<]<<
```

Answer (score 0):

## TIS-100, 8 operations

```
MOV ACC UP #A
SUB UP     #B
SUB 999
ADD 999
ADD UP     #B
SUB UP     #C
SUB 999
ADD 999
ADD UP     #C
MOV ACC DOWN
```

The provider(UP) only do MOVs so not shown in the code
Maybe not work when too near the 999 edge

Answer (score -1):

VBA (6 tokens)

```
 Function max3(a As Integer, b As Integer, c As Integer)
 i = IIf(a >= b And a >= c, a, IIf(b >= c, b, c))
 max3 = i
 End Function
```

not sure if this is not branching.

Comment: It is branching, only inline. Specifically, the ubiquitous ternary operator (which this essentially is) is not one of the allowed operations.

Comment: Thanks @tomsmeding, may I ask what is the ubiquitous ternary operator (is it IIF() in my code?)

Comment: yes sorry, with ubiquitous I meant that it's present in pretty much every language, and the ternary operator is your `IIf`, Inline-If. In most languages, it is, for example, `a>=b ? a : b`. It is branching indeed.

Answer (score -1):

### JavaScript: 4 tokens (** based on broad interpretation of "assignment"!)

Obviously my score of 4 is extremely generous/lenient!

To arrive at that score I've assumed "assignment" (worth 0 tokens in the question) includes such things as additive assignment, subtractive assignment, multiplicative assignment, and XOR-ing (`^=`) assignment

```javascript
function f(a, b, c) {
  d = a;
  d -= b;
  d = d >= 0;

  a *= d;  //a = a if (a>=b), else 0
  d ^= true; //invert d
  b *= d;  //b = b if (b<a), else 0

  a += b;  //a is now max(a,b)

  d = a;
  d -= c;
  d = d >= 0;

  a *= d;  //a = a if (a>=c), else 0
  d ^= true; //invert d
  c *= d;  //c = c if (c<a), else 0
  a += c;  //a is now max(max(a,b),c)

  return a;
}
```

If those assignments actually count the score is 14 :)

Comment: Because `d -= b` is actually the same as `d = d - b`, I would say that you use arithmetic and that you should count this as a token.

Comment: Yes, I realise that - I was (jokingly) trying to take advantage of the meaning of "assignment".  I think I made that fairly obvious!